# remove duplicate records with a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using a script which requires only unique values. And I have a table which has duplicates like below, i need to keep only unique values (first occurrence) irrespective of what is present inside the brackets.

can I delete the records and keep the unique records using a single query?

Input table

```
ID  Name        
1   (Del)testing    
2   (Del)test       
3   (Delete)testing 
4   (Delete)tester      
5   (Del)tst        
6   (Delete)tst
```

So the output tables should be something like

Input table

```
ID  Name        
1   (Del)testing    
2   (Del)test       
3   (Delete) tester     
4   (Del)tst
```

Comment: You can get the unique values of the name field, but if you want to preserve consecutive id's, then it's much more involved.

Comment: Your sample output is contradictory to your accepted solution. Please edit it so that the two are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM FOO;
```

It depends how much data you have to retrieve, if you only have to change Delete -> Del you can try with REPLACE

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

also grouping functions should help you

I don't think this would be easy query

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: The `name` column always has all strings in the format given in the sample data.

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, rank() over 
 (partition by substring(name, charindex(')',name)+1,len(name)+1 - charindex(')',name))
 order by id) rn
 from tbl
),

filtered_cte as
(select * from cte
 where rn = 1
)

select rank() over (partition by getdate() order by id,getdate()) id , name
from filtered_cte
```

How this works:

1. The first CTE `cte` uses `rank()` to rank the occurrence of the string outside brackets in the `name` column.
2. The second CTE `filtered_cte` only returns the first row for each occurence of the specified string. In this step, we get the expected results, but not in the desired format.
3. In this step we `partition by` and `order by` the `getdate()` function. This function is chosen as a dummy to give us continuous values for the `id` column while using the `rank` function as we did in step 1.

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/XAKSLK56914).

Note that this solution will return filtered values, but not delete anything in the source table. If you wish, you can delete from the CTE created in step 1 to remove data from the source table.

Answer (score 0):

First use this update to make them uniform

```
Update table set name = replace(Name, '(Del)' , '(Delete)')
```

then delete the repetitive names

```
Delete from table where id in
(Select id from (Select Row_Number() over(Partition by Name order by id) as rn,* from table) x
where rn > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the input date table
    CREATE TABLE test
    (`ID` int,`Name` varchar(20));

```
INSERT INTO test
(`ID`, `Name`)
VALUES
(1,  '(Del)testing'),
(2, '(Del)test'),
(3,  '(Delete)testing'),
(4,  '(Delete)tester'),
(5, '(Del)tst'),
    (6, '(Delete)tst');
```

Select Query

```
select id,  name
from (
select id,  name ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY substring(name,PATINDEX('%)%',name)+1,20) ORDER BY name) rn 
from test ) t
where rn= 1 
order by 1
```

SQL Fiddle Link

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a02b0/34